# Stateful beans and Stateless beans in Spring context

Tags: spring

I am reading spring through its official documentation and at one place I came to a line that uses prototype scope for all stateful beans while singleton for stateless beans.

I know there is something as stateful as well as stateless beans in EJB but this is not what they have mentioned in the documents.

Can anyone explain to me what exactly this means of stateful as well stateless beans in Spring

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a link to the part of the Spring docs that say this?

Comment: here is the link   http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From spring perspective

- stateless beans: beans that are singleton and are initialized only once. The only state they have is a shared state. These beans are created while the `ApplicationContext` is being initialized. The SAME bean instance will be returned/injected during the lifetime of this `ApplicationContext`.
- stateful beans: beans that can carry state (instance variables). These are created EVERY time an object is required (like using the "new" operator in java).

These are not EJB statfull/stateless session beans.

Comment: When you declare the statefull beans in Spring? also in the application context or anywhere else?

Comment: @Pangea one thing I don't understand is when singleton beans are of shared state then why are they called stateless? Anyways they will maintain the state of the shared variables.

Comment: @weakstudent, singletons in Spring are not the same as those described by GoF (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-global-session). Basically, a well written spring bean should be stateless with only dependency injected, thread local, instance variables. With that in mind, there's really no "global state" or shared state to speak of.

Comment: Stateless are not singletons! They are pooled, and you don't have to deal with concurrency

Comment: @cocorossello, How many instances of a stateless bean would exist typically? Are they created initially when they are required and then pooled for later use? Say there's only one stateless bean in the pool and two clients are trying to access it. Is a new stateless bean created in that case?

Comment: stateless beans: beans that are singleton and are initialized only once. Then why this is default in spring? If only one instance for that bean, then the property it holds will be continued overwritten, then would be very chaos? User A request a singleton bean X, modify it, but then User B request bean X also and overwrite bean X, then User A save bean X, then will be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in storing specific information like client data, per request data in Singleton bean as they are created only once by Spring IOC container. That's why singleton beans are stateless. They are shared resources. They can only be used for storing global information.

When a request is made for creating a prototype bean, a new request is created every time. So, they can be used to store some specific information for each request. So they are stateful.

Comment: Singleton bean:They are shared resources. They can only be used for storing global information.
Yes, but then why spring default is singleton bean? When we write application, it is more often that we need an object for storing user specific information, not system global information.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the implementation. See tomee for example http://tomee.apache.org/statelesscontainer-config.html . You'll have to check in your server docs