# Stateful and stateless beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, stateless, stateful

What do *stateful* and *stateless* beans in Spring mean?
I googled it a lot but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: learn to google better, with no knowledge about the subject and about 10s invested, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506241/stateful-beans-and-stateless-beans-in-spring-context

Answer (score 3):

State is most commonly represented by field variable that is not autowired.

So this is stateful bean:

```
@Component
public class Stateful {
    private int someCounter;

    ...
}
```

Stateless is bean one that doesn't have any class level variables or only  autowired singleton bean instances to Stateless types.

Basically everything that can change the value within that bean and it's dependency tree (except local variables in methods) is state and should be avoided as much as possible.

So my example is thread-unsafe antipattern, because such defined bean is singleton. And singleton bean must be stateless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is really helpful. What pattern would you recommend if this way has flaws? I was considering in-memory, completely cached in application's memory, use cases with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows for Singleton and Prototype bean scopes (plus `request`, `session` and `global session` for HTTP context).

Singleton means - there will only be 1 instance created of that class for the whole application context, or basically for the whole lifetime of an application (unless you have multiple contexts)

Every time a bean of that Singleton scoped class is requested by either getBean or is injected during runtime, it will be the same instance.

Prototype means - everytime a bean is requested by getBean or is injected, a new instance will be created. You should use this scope for beans which are stateful (have data saved in their instance variables).

Comment: So you mean if I instantiate a prototype bean and call some method on it, it will create a new bean and then call that method on the new bean? that doesn't sound correct, could you please cite some reference for it, what's the point of maintaining state if I can't call a method on it

Comment: @Akshay new instance will not be created every time you call a method on it, but it will be created every time the bean is injected or looked up using getBean. You are right in saying that creating new instances on calling a method is incorrect. I will adjust the answer.