# Spring Boot - How to get the running port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, port, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a spring boot application (using embedded tomcat 7), and I've set `server.port = 0` in my `application.properties` so I can have a random port.  After the server is booted up and running on a port, I need to be able to get the port that that was chosen.

I cannot use `@Value("$server.port")` because it's zero.  This is a seemingly simple piece of information, so why can't I access it from my java code?  How can I access it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24643484/1686330

Comment: Another possibility can be found in the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html (see 64.5 Discover the HTTP port at runtime )

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thanks to @Dirk Lachowski for pointing me in the right direction.  The solution isn't as elegant as I would have liked, but I got it working.  Reading the spring docs, I can listen on the EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent and get the port once the server is up and running.  Here's what it looks like -

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;




    @Component
    public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent> {

      @Override
      public void onApplicationEvent(final EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent event) {
          int thePort = event.getEmbeddedServletContainer().getPort();
      }
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK this won't work if you're looking to configure a bean with the server port. This event isn't fired off until after all the beans have been loaded and the servlets have been registered.

Comment: it worked for me at the time thats why I accepted it.  I haven't tried hennr's answer though.

Comment: After reading the docs I came up with virtually the same small class as you, naming it `PortProvider`, and providing a `getPort()` method. Autowired my `PortProvider` in to the controller needing the port, and when my business logic called `portProvider.getPort()`, the runtime port was returned.

Comment: For anyone trying this with Spring Boot 2.0 or later, the API seems to have changed slightly. I was no longer able to subscribe to `EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent`, but there is a similar class called `ServletWebServerInitializedEvent` which has a `.getWebServer()` method. This will get you the port Tomcat is listening to at least.

Answer (score 131):

Is it also possible to access the management port in a similar way, e.g.:

```
  @SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
  public class MyTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;

    @LocalManagementPort
    int randomManagementPort;
```

Comment: [`@LocalServerPort`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/LocalServerPort.html) is just a shortcut for `@Value("${local.server.port}")`.

Comment: @deamon means if you not specify local.server.port in properties - it wont works

Comment: Using `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"

Answer (score 103):

Spring's Environment holds this information for you.

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;

String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
```

On the surface this looks identical to injecting a field annotated `@Value("${local.server.port}")` (or `@LocalServerPort`, which is identical), whereby an autowiring failure is thrown at startup as the value isn't available until the context is fully initialised. The difference here is that this call is implicitly being made in runtime business logic rather than invoked at application startup, and hence the 'lazy-fetch' of the port resolves ok.

Comment: for some reason this didnt work for me, `environment.getProperty("server.port")` did.

Comment: in my case `port` is `null`.
```@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SpringBootH2IntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port"); // null here
}
```

After adding: `webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` next to `SpringBootTest` I see port.

Comment: This is because @SpringBootTest defaults to a MockMVC environment, not starting an apllication server that could provide a port.

Answer (score 18):

You can get the port that is being used by an embedded Tomcat instance during tests by injecting the local.server.port value as such:

```
// Inject which port we were assigned
@Value("${local.server.port}")
int port;
```

Comment: `local.server.port` is only set when running with `@WebIntegrationTests`

Comment: [WebIntegrationTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/WebIntegrationTest.html) is Deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

Just so others who have configured their apps like mine benefit from what I went through...

None of the above solutions worked for me because I have a `./config` directory just under my project base with 2 files:
`application.properties`
`application-dev.properties`
In `application.properties` I have:

```
spring.profiles.active = dev  # set my default profile to 'dev'
```

In `application-dev.properties` I have:

```
server_host = localhost
server_port = 8080
```

This is so when I run my fat jar from the CLI the `*.properties` files will be read from the `./config` dir and all is good.

Well, it turns out that these properties files completely override the `webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` setting in  `@SpringBootTest` in my Spock specs. No matter what I tried, even with `webEnvironment` set to `RANDOM_PORT` Spring would always startup the embedded Tomcat container on port 8080 (or whatever value I'd set in my `./config/*.properties` files).

The **ONLY** way I was able to overcome this was by adding an explicit `properties = "server_port=0"` to the `@SpringBootTest` annotation in my Spock integration specs:

```
@SpringBootTest (webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = "server_port=0")
```

Then, and only then did Spring finally start to spin up Tomcat on a random port. IMHO this is a Spring testing framework bug, but I'm sure they'll have their own opinion on this.

Hope this helped someone.

Comment: Have this exact same setup and also ran into this. I assumed this was the issue in some sense, but thanks for posting your solution here. Do you know if anyone has logged this as a bug yet?

Answer (score 12):

Starting with Spring Boot 1.4.0 you can use this in your test:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.LocalServerPort;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  int randomPort;

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

After Spring Boot 2, a lot has changed. The above given answers work prior to Spring Boot 2. Now if you are running your application with runtime arguments for the server port, then you will only get the static value with `@Value("${server.port}")`, that is mentioned in the **application.properties** file. Now to get the actual port in which the server is running, use the following method:

```java
    @Autowired
    private ServletWebServerApplicationContext server;

    @GetMapping("/server-port")
    public String serverPort() {

        return "" + server.getWebServer().getPort();
    }
```

Also, if you are using your applications as Eureka/Discovery Clients with load balanced `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`, the above method will return the exact port number.

Comment: This is the right answer for Spring Boot 2.  Works fine with  @SpringBootTest and WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT.

Comment: Just to supplement the comment of @Ken Pronovici - if webEnvironment parameter is not specified in SpringBootTest annotation, the Spring doesn't create the ServletWebServerApplicationContext and fails at runtime because it can't find a candidate bean to inject

Comment: Tried this and always 0 to me.

Answer (score 8):

None of these solutions worked for me. I needed to know the server port while constructing a Swagger configuration bean. Using [ServerProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.html) worked for me:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig 
{
    @Inject
    private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties serverProperties;

    public JerseyConfig() 
    {
        property(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void postConstruct()
    {
        // register application endpoints
        registerAndConfigureSwaggerUi();
    }

    private void registerAndConfigureSwaggerUi()
    {
        register(ApiListingResource.class);
        register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

        final BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
        // set other properties
        config.setHost("localhost:" + serverProperties.getPort()); // gets server.port from application.properties file         
    }
}
```

This example uses Spring Boot auto configuration and JAX-RS (not Spring MVC).

Comment: I wanted the same thing for swagger

Answer (score 3):

I'm in Spring 2.5.5 and use Junit 4.13.2, here is my solution:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

// tell Java the environment your testcase running is in Spring, 
// which will enable the auto configuration such as value injection
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    class = Application.class, 
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SimpleWebTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int randomPort;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // use randomPort ...
        System.out.println(randomPort);
    }

}
```

Comment: Deprecated since 2.7.0 for removal in 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have imported the correct package

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
```

and then use the Environment object

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;    // Environment Object containts the port number

 @GetMapping("/status")
  public String status()
    {
   return "it is runing on"+(env.getProperty("local.server.port"));
    }
```

Comment: I have made changes to my answer are you still having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the server port from the

```java
HttpServletRequest
```

```java
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

@GetMapping(value = "/port")
public Object getServerPort() {
   System.out.println("I am from " + request.getServerPort());
   return "I am from  " + request.getServerPort();
}
```

Comment: I think that's a bad idea. The information can be retrieved when a request ist made. Probably one wants to know the port on startup before the first request is made.

Comment: Another issue which could be severe if wrongly adapted is that the HttpServletRequest is set as a private member variable of a controller class.
When having two request at the 'same' time the setting of 'request' will be overwritten since the class is a singleton (isn't it? - let me know) If it was thread-wise the implementation would be ok. (also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506382/845117)

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot 3.0 listening for `ServletWebServerInitializedEvent` event seems to be the best idea, as the server TCP port  becomes to be known at some certain point in time. No earlier!

So you can add such a bean:

```
    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ServletWebServerInitializedEvent> serverPortListenerBean() {
        return event -> {
            int serverPort = event.getWebServer().getPort();
            // TODO do something with the `serverPort`
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works only in case you have `local.server.port` in `application.properties`.

```
@LocalServerPort
int randomServerPort;
```

it's equal to

```
@Value("{local.server.port}")
int randomServerPort;
```

the `@LocalServerPort` annotation is depreciated in springboot3

As `server.port` is a native property in springboot instead of `local.server.port`, you can simply use

```
@Value("{server.port}")
int randomServerPort;
```

just make sure you have something like `server.port=8080` in `application.properties`

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with a kind of proxy bean. The client gets initialized when it is needed, by then the port should be available:

```
@Component
public class GraphQLClient {

    private ApolloClient apolloClient;
    private final Environment environment;

    public GraphQLClient(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public ApolloClient getApolloClient() {
        if (apolloClient == null) {
            String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
            initApolloClient(port);
        }
        return apolloClient;
    }

    public synchronized void initApolloClient(String port) {
        this.apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
                .serverUrl("http://localhost:" + port + "/graphql")
                .build();
    }

    public <D extends Operation.Data, T, V extends Operation.Variables> GraphQLCallback<T> graphql(Operation<D, T, V> operation) {
        GraphQLCallback<T> graphQLCallback = new GraphQLCallback<>();
        if (operation instanceof Query) {
            Query<D, T, V> query = (Query<D, T, V>) operation;
            getApolloClient()
                    .query(query)
                    .enqueue(graphQLCallback);
        } else {
            Mutation<D, T, V> mutation = (Mutation<D, T, V>) operation;
            getApolloClient()
                    .mutate(mutation)
                    .enqueue(graphQLCallback);

        }
        return graphQLCallback;
    }
}
```