# Spring Boot Server Port

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, properties

I changed the `server.port=8190` in `application.properties`, but the server is accessible from both ports `8190` and `8080`.
How to completely override `8080` port?

Comment: Where did you define the port ?

Comment: @ASdi If you read the question, it already says that the port is defined in the `application.properties` file.

Comment: Have you checked that there isn't any other instances of tomcat running? Try stopping spring boot and try to load the app on `8190` does it still work?

Comment: I mean you may overwrite it somewhere else like program arguments

Comment: @px06 I checked, just one instance of tomcat is running. I stopped everything and started the app with `java -jar app.jar`

Comment: Try removing `server.port=...` from your `application.properties` file and start the app using `java -jar app.jar --server.port=8080`, also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port) to debug and see what port Spring is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had dependencies for tomcat in build.gradle:

```
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.8")
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.5.8")
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.5.2")
```

I removed the above lines and now the server is running only on port `8190`.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that you have an additonal 'zombie' tomcat process still running. Are you sure only one tomcat instance is getting started up by spring boot?

Alternatively try:

`java -Dserver.port=8190 -jar app.jar`