# Using Spock Testing Framework with Spring Boot to test my REST Controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spock

### situation

I have a spring boot application that run a simple REST Service. I want to test this service. Since I love Spock Framework I'd love to use it here but I can't get pass the issue with the Spring Configuration.

### problem

The test itself does run but is throwing a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` exception. The issue here is that the actual application I want to test against is not running - therefore there is not REST interface available. How can I assure that the actual application is running before the test runs? Using JUnit this concern was kinda trivial since Spring has its annotations for that. But what about Spock?

*Edit*: I tried to use the following article: http://henningpetersen.com/post/18/testing-spring-mvc-controllers-with-spock

**RestHandler.java**

```
@RestController
public class RestHandler {

  private @Autowired ExecutionService executionService;

  public RestHandler(ExecutionService executionService) {
    this.executionService = executionService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/toolbox/exec", method = POST,
          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
          produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
  public String executeTool(@RequestBody Tool tool) {
    executionService.execute(tool);
    return "thanks";
  }

}
```

**ToolExecutor.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ToolExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToolExecutor.class, args);
    }
}
```

**RestHandlerTest.groovy**

```
@SpringBootTest
class RestHandlerTest extends Specification {

    def someService = Mock(ExecutionService)
    def underTest = new RestHandler(someService);
    def mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(underTest).build()

    @Shared
    def client = new RESTClient("http://localhost:603/toolbox/exec")

    def "ExecuteToolTest"() {
        when: "If POST has valid JSON format"
        Closure object = { "{\"name\":\"test\",\"parameters\":[\"abc\",\"def\"]}" }
        def response = client.request(Method.POST, object);
        then:
        with(response){
            data.text == "thanks"
            status == 200
        }

    }
}
```

**LOG**

```
    15:22:07.601 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15:22:07.605 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15:22:07.605 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
15:22:07.855 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking for request mappings in application context: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@17f9d882
15:22:07.897 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - 2 request handler methods found on class com.company.toolbox.components.executor.RestHandler: {public void com.company.toolbox.components.executor.RestHandler.isAlive()={[/toolbox/exec],methods=[GET]}, public java.lang.String com.company.toolbox.components.executor.RestHandler.executeTool(com.company.toolbox.commons.Tool)={[/toolbox/exec],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[text/plain]}}
15:22:07.900 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/toolbox/exec],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.company.toolbox.components.executor.RestHandler.isAlive()
15:22:07.907 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/toolbox/exec],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[text/plain]}" onto public java.lang.String com.company.toolbox.components.executor.RestHandler.executeTool(com.company.toolbox.commons.Tool)
15:22:08.285 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
15:22:08.286 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.4.Final
15:22:08.307 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
15:22:08.317 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom MessageInterpolator of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator
15:22:08.318 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom ParameterNameProvider of type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26
15:22:08.320 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
15:22:08.323 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
15:22:08.324 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
15:22:08.324 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
15:22:08.386 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@17f9d882
15:22:08.422 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Looking for exception mappings: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@17f9d882
15:22:08.442 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Initializing servlet ''
15:22:08.452 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15:22:08.452 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15:22:08.455 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15:22:08.455 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15:22:08.455 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
15:22:08.455 [main] INFO org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ''
15:22:08.455 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization started
15:22:08.457 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Unable to locate MultipartResolver with name 'multipartResolver': no multipart request handling provided
15:22:08.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using LocaleResolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@267f474e]
15:22:08.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using ThemeResolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@7a7471ce]
15:22:08.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using RequestToViewNameTranslator [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@28276e50]
15:22:08.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using FlashMapManager [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@62e70ea3]
15:22:08.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet '' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.]
15:22:08.458 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 3 ms
15:22:08.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Servlet '' configured successfully
15:22:08.476 [main] DEBUG groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - POST http://localhost:603/toolbox/exec
15:22:08.728 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {}->http://localhost:603
15:22:08.742 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost:603
15:22:09.744 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connect to localhost:603 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
15:22:09.745 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost:603
15:22:10.745 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@21362712 closed
15:22:10.745 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@21362712 shut down
15:22:10.746 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@27eb3298
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:476)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:373)
    at com.xetra11.toolbox.components.executor.RestHandlerTest.ExecuteToolTest(RestHandlerTest.groovy:26)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Check the logs. What port is the spring boot app starting on inside the test?

Comment: I already tried to change the port to *8080* as I thought about that this TestServer could not know of my custom port setup via properties. Still no Luck. I then tried to figure out the actual port through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port - no luck either - these annotation did not worked in this case it seemed.

Comment: I also added a *application.properties* in the test-resources and set `server.port=603` - no luck as well

Comment: You seem to be mixing MockMvc with actual HTTP requests. You need to choose one or the other and configure and write your tests accordingly

Comment: Okay that might be the case - but just because I cannot find a way to test this with Spring - that is in fact my actual question. The case that I want to server to be running is just because I cannot see another way to perform actions with groovys "RESTClient" class to get some results of the REST interface I provide. What I really want to know is how to test a REST Controller created with Spring, with the Spock Testing Framework

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class RestHandlerTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate
```

And then you use testRestTemplate instead of client. You also need to add spock-spring dependency.