# Can access Spring Boot's @LocalServerPort in Spock's setup but not setupSpec

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spock

I'm trying to set up a test that will hit a Spring Boot MVC endpoint (`http://localhost:$port/api/v1/beer` in my case) using Spock and the [GOJI HTTP client](https://github.com/tomtom-international/goji-http-client). I would like to set up the HTTP client once, in `setupSpec`. Since I'm using `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)`, I need to get the randomly-assigned port in order to provide it to the HTTP client's constructor: `beerClient = new HttpClient(baseUrl: "http://localhost:$localPort")`. To do this, I have a field `localPort` annotated with both Spock's `@Shared` and Spring Boot's `@org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort`. Unfortunately, the value of `localPort` is null. However, if I leave off the `@Shared` annotations on the HTTP client declaration and on `localPort` and use `setup` instead of `setupSpec`, `localPort` *does* have a value. What is causing this difference? Test class is below.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class BeerControllerOpenApiTest extends Specification {
//    @Shared
    @LocalServerPort
    Integer localPort

//    @Shared
    HttpClient beerClient

//    void setupSpec() {
//        beerClient = new HttpClient(baseUrl: "http://localhost:$localPort")
//    }
    void setup() {
        beerClient = new HttpClient(baseUrl: "http://localhost:$localPort")
    }

    def "test list beers"() {
        when:
        def response = beerClient.get(
            path: "/api/v1/beer",
            headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
        )

        then:
        response.statusCode == 200
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239369/spring-boot-test-failing-to-autowire-port-with-localserverport-annotation

Comment: I tried adding `@ContextConfiguration` as well as making the test implement `ApplicationListener`, but neither approach got the port to have a value in `setupSpec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring context is not loaded when `setupSpec()` is executed, so you can't access anything from it.

If you only want to do it once I'd suggest to move the `HttpClient` declaration into the Spring context, e.g., by using `@TestContext`. Alternatively, you can use a `@Shared` field and a simple `if` condition.

```
    @Shared
    HttpClient beerClient

    void setup() {
        if(beerClient == null)
            beerClient = new HttpClient(baseUrl: "http://localhost:$localPort")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like the if check. Nice and simple. Thanks!