# How to get server port in spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have Spring Boot 1.5.3 application. There is a line `server.port = 8081` in application.properties file. 
Now I want to test ping method:

```
private final Environment environment;

@Autowired
public ServerCommunicateServiceImpl(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

@Override
public boolean pingHost(String host) {
    int port = environment.getProperty("server.port", Integer.class, DEFAULT_PORT);
    return pingHost(host, port, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ServerCommunicateServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private ServerCommunicateService serverCommunicateService;

    @Test
    public void pingHost() {
        boolean result = serverCommunicateService.pingHost("localhost");
        assertThat(result, is(true));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work because port is `-1`. The environment have 4 property sources and first of it contains property `server.port = -1`. I need port from `application.properties` file.

It works on production but not works in tests.

Comment: check this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port

Comment: you probably need to set you envirnoment to DEV somewhere

Comment: @tharanga-dinesh profile is dev. It doesn't work.
Also `local.server.port` is null

Comment: By default `@SpringBootTest` runs with a mocked environment and hence doesn't have a port assigned. If you want to run with an actual port change the `webEnvironment` of `@SpringBootTest` to something else.

Comment: @M. Deinum, thank you very much. It works now.