# How to get the running server port in a SpringBoot test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating some unit tests for a spring boot application with an Apache Camel route, using Spock as testing framework, and I need to mock a response from another application. I made a mock controller for that, but i need to inject the port that the test is running in to a property. Is there a way to get the port that the test is running on?

I tried with

```
@LocalServerPort
private int port
```

and with

```
@Autowired Environment environment;
String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
```

but both return a -1, I don´t know any other ways to get the port

My test is configured with the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles('test')
```

Also, is there a way to inject that random port in the `application-test.yml` file? Ideally I would need to do something like this in my `application-test.yml` file:

```
app:
  service: localhost:${server.port}
```

Where the port is the random port that the test is running on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628943/spring-boot-how-to-get-running-port-and-ip-address

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301056/how-to-get-server-port-in-spring-boot-test

Comment: hi guys, those answers didn´t work for me, each return a null for the port

Answer (score 4):

Could you try this :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public class test{

    @LocalServerPort
    private int rdmServerPort;

    @LocalManagementPort
    private int rdmManagementPort;
        ...
}
```

Comment: `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` is key here. If you use the default mock web environment, no embedded container is started. As a result, there's no port involved and `-1` will be injected.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson looks like op is already using that. If using `RANDOM_PORT` is there a way to reference it in the property file like OP says `app.service=localhost:${server.port}` (with server.port not beind explicitly defined)