# Spring Boot - How to get the port at runtime without using spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a generic java agent based on aspectj which runs on several spring boot applications (and several spring boot versions).
I'm trying to find a way to get the port on runtime, programatically when the application STARTS (before a request is made).
The problem -

1. I cannot use the regular way to get a spring boot port such as the ones described in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port%20Spring%20Boot%20-%20How%20to%20get%20the%20running%20port) which includes @Autowired annotation etc.
2. I'm looking for the port after the applications starts, without relying on requests to be made.

I'm looking for a way to access the LocalServerPort object or any other options that will allow me to access the port.

thanks for any help

Comment: This sounds like a questionably hacky situation (it's usually better to *tell* the application what port to use), but you could try something with a static holder and a runner that sets a value there.

Comment: `@LocalServerPort` is only for tests and not runtime. So trying to get that at runtime will simply fail because it isn't there (it is test only!). The agent should get the `ServerProperties` and look at the `port` if that has been set use it else use the default `8080`. However still feels hacky and looks like you are trying to do things at the wrong location.

Comment: @chrylis it is indeed not a standard case, but rather a tricky one...Can you give me an example of what you mean by a static holder and a runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, as I mentioned I'm working with aspectj,I used the following instrumentation:

```
 after():
         execution(org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainer+.new(..))
```

And took the port directly from the EmbeddedServletContainer instance using the getPort() method.
In case of Tomcat, if the port is -1, I use the embedded tomcat object to get the port from the connector itself.